# Using @FindBy to find an element. Refactoring and best practices

Tags: java, selenium, testing, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I currently have this method in my selenium framework.

```
public void selectAddProductButton() {
    driver.findElement(By.id("Content")).findElement(By.className("Title")).findElement(By.tagName("a")).click();
}
```

However, I like it and I don't like it. I feel like this is a dirty way to approaching this. I thought it would be better to use @FindBy but I don't see how I could. I've read online that I can achieve this by using the @FindBy with an xpath. However, I've also read that using xpath this way is a bad practice. Is there a better way I can do this? I usually use @FindBy for more simple things. An example would be

```
@FindBy(id = "firstname")
private WebElement firstName;
```

I don't think there is a way to find an element that is nested within other elements  using @FindBy unless I used xpath

Comment: Where did you read "using xpath ... is a bad practice"? That is completely false!

Comment: Okay, maybe not bad practice. But maybe that it should be the last option I use before any of my other options, as it is not as clear and concise.

Comment: Most of the assumptions in your post above are incorrect. You might want to do a little more research, and perhaps a small proof of concept. Your post, as is, in danger of getting closed for being off topic. Please have a read through [ask].

Comment: As @SiKing says, your assumptions are flat out incorrect.  There was a time when XPath was slow (and I mean REALLY SLOW) compared to the other options, but that was all cleared up years ago.  Also, I normally steer clear from the FindBy annotations simply because of the StateElementException issues that arise as a result.  Your original code, however, could be greatly improved by using an xpath or css selector:   By.cssSelector("#Content .Title a") or By.xpath("//*[@id='Content']//*[contains(@class, 'Title')]//a")

Comment: `@FindBy` is an absolutely **essential** component of `PageFactory` https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory , which I find to be a very stable and excellent approach to building your `PageObject` classes. I have no idea what you would do with this annotation outside of that. Not sure what @alhot is talking about "StateElementException issues that arise as a result".

Answer (score 2):

Of course. You actually have multiple other options along with `xpath`. In that case you need to use another paramter. `how = How.ID`

**Example**

```
FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "foobar") WebElement foobar;
```

Find Java doc [here](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/FindBy.html)

Enum How provides you all the following options:

• css

• id

• linkText

• name

• partialLinkText

• tagName

• using

• xpath

Comment: Haha when I meant "this" I actually was referring to the longer one.
driver.findElement(By.id("Content")).findElement(By.className("Title")).findElement(By.tagName("a")).click();
Is there anyway I can make THIS better by using some @FindBy

Comment: What is your question then?